# How to connect to jhipster registry running in docker with microservice in intellj

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, jhipster

I have an spring boot application which is dockerized, while it is dockerized I can connect without any problems to my jhipster-registry inside the same docker-compose. But when I am trying to start my application with intellj idea in order to test new implementations I am getting the following error:

```
com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.TransportException: Cannot execute request on any known server
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient.execute(RetryableEurekaHttpClient.java:112)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.register(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:56)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$1.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:59)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.SessionedEurekaHttpClient.execute(SessionedEurekaHttpClient.java:77)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.register(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:56)
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.register(DiscoveryClient.java:876)
    at com.netflix.discovery.InstanceInfoReplicator.run(InstanceInfoReplicator.java:121)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)

2022-07-07 14:48:02.062  WARN 18203 --- [freshExecutor-0] c.n.d.s.t.d.RetryableEurekaHttpClient    : Request execution failed with message: I/O error on GET request for "http://admin:admin@jhipster-registry:8761/eureka/apps/": jhipster-registry; nested exception is java.net.UnknownHostException: jhipster-registry
2022-07-07 14:48:02.062  INFO 18203 --- [freshExecutor-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_PRODUCT/product:88e7f82cd95d241292a79dd4f76716a8 - was unable to refresh its cache! This periodic background refresh will be retried in 10 seconds. status = Cannot execute request on any known server stacktrace = com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.TransportException: Cannot execute request on any known server
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient.execute(RetryableEurekaHttpClient.java:112)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$6.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:137)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.SessionedEurekaHttpClient.execute(SessionedEurekaHttpClient.java:77)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134)
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.getAndStoreFullRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:1101)
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.fetchRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:1014)
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.refreshRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:1531)
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient$CacheRefreshThread.run(DiscoveryClient.java:1498)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

This is how my docker jhipster registry is configured:

```
jhipster-registry:
    image: jhipster/jhipster-registry:v7.3.0
    volumes:
      - ./central-server-config:/central-config
    # By default the JHipster Registry runs with the "dev" and "native"
    # Spring profiles.
    # "native" profile means the filesystem is used to store data, see
    # http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/spring-cloud-config.html
    environment:
      - _JAVA_OPTIONS=-Xmx512m -Xms256m
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=dev
      - SPRING_SECURITY_USER_PASSWORD=admin
      - JHIPSTER_REGISTRY_PASSWORD=admin
      - SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_SERVER_COMPOSITE_0_TYPE=native
      - SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_SERVER_COMPOSITE_0_SEARCH_LOCATIONS=file:./central-config
      # - SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_SERVER_COMPOSITE_0_TYPE=git
      # - SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_SERVER_COMPOSITE_0_URI=https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-registry/
      # - SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_SERVER_COMPOSITE_0_SEARCH_PATHS=central-config
      - MANAGEMENT_METRICS_EXPORT_PROMETHEUS_ENABLED=true
    ports:
      - 8761:8761
```

central server config:

```
#common configuration shared between all applications
configserver:
  name: Docker JHipster Registry
  status: Connected to the JHipster Registry running in Docker

jhipster:
  security:
    authentication:
      jwt:
        base64-secret: MzEyMjE4N2FmMmMyNmFjMmQ4ODk0NzAzNjNhNmRkYTUxNzBkZjVkMTM4NDIwM2VmZjhkMTJjMTUyNjczZWUxNzIwZGI4ZWQ5YmZhNjk3MGU5ZmE4NTU2NWNkZGJkYTE3NTMyNWFhNmE4YzdjZTk5NGRhMGY5NTBkMWM2ODBkYmE=
management:
  metrics:
    export:
      prometheus:
        enabled: true
eureka:
  client:
    service-url:
      defaultZone: http://admin:${jhipster.registry.password}@jhipster-registry:8761/eureka/
```

And this is the config of my spring boot application (dev)

```
logging:
  level:
    ROOT: DEBUG
    tech.jhipster: DEBUG
    org.hibernate.SQL: DEBUG
    com.moniesta.product: DEBUG

eureka:
  instance:
    prefer-ip-address: true
  client:
    service-url:
      defaultZone: http://admin:${jhipster.registry.password}@localhost:8761/eureka/

spring:
  devtools:
    restart:
      enabled: true
      additional-exclude: static/**,.h2.server.properties
    livereload:
      enabled: false # we use Webpack dev server + BrowserSync for livereload
  jackson:
    serialization:
      indent-output: true
  cloud:
    config:
      uri: http://admin:${jhipster.registry.password}@localhost:8761/config
      # name of the config server's property source (file.yml) that we want to use
      name: product
      profile: dev
      label: main # toggle to switch to a different version of the configuration as stored in git
      # it can be set to any label, branch or commit of the configuration source Git repository
  datasource:
    type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:product;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
    username: product
    password:
    hikari:
      poolName: Hikari
      auto-commit: false
  h2:
    console:
      # disable spring boot built-in h2-console since we start it manually with correct configuration
      enabled: true
  jpa:
    database-platform: tech.jhipster.domain.util.FixedH2Dialect
    generate-ddl: on
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update

  liquibase:
    # Remove 'faker' if you do not want the sample data to be loaded automatically
    contexts: dev, faker
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:product;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE


  messages:
    cache-duration: PT1S # 1 second, see the ISO 8601 standard
  thymeleaf:
    cache: false
  sleuth:
    # https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/27844#issuescomment-1002866885
    # https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/issues/2094
    async:
      enabled: false
    enabled: false
    sampler:
      probability: 1 # report 100% of traces
  zipkin: # Use the "zipkin" Maven profile to have the Spring Cloud Zipkin dependencies
    base-url: http://localhost:9411
    enabled: false
    locator:
      discovery:
        enabled: true

server:
  port: 8081

# ===================================================================
# JHipster specific properties
#
# Full reference is available at: https://www.jhipster.tech/common-application-properties/
# ===================================================================

jhipster:
  cache: # Cache configuration
    hazelcast: # Hazelcast distributed cache
      time-to-live-seconds: 3600
      backup-count: 1
  registry:
    password: admin
  # CORS is disabled by default on microservices, as you should access them through a gateway.
  # If you want to enable it, please uncomment the configuration below.
  # cors:
  #   allowed-origins: "http://localhost:9000,https://localhost:9000"
  #   allowed-methods: "*"
  #   allowed-headers: "*"
  #   exposed-headers: "Authorization,Link,X-Total-Count"
  #   allow-credentials: true
  #   max-age: 1800
  security:
    authentication:
      jwt:
        # This token must be encoded using Base64 and be at least 256 bits long (you can type `openssl rand -base64 64` on your command line to generate a 512 bits one)
        base64-secret: NWRhMTc4MTY0MDBmNzc2YmY1NzgzNmU0ZmQ2MmUyZGFkNTdhMmM4MWQ0OTU2YjI5MzY4YjJiMjllMzRmYjVmNWM5NjNhNjdjOTcxMmM1M2Y3OGFkZDNhNTQyNDViZmFlZGY4ZTU5MTMwNjM1MTNmMjkzYjA4OTcyMWEyNTA5ZWQ=
        # Token is valid 24 hours
        token-validity-in-seconds: 86400
        token-validity-in-seconds-for-remember-me: 2592000
  logging:
    use-json-format: false # By default, logs are not in Json format
    logstash: # Forward logs to logstash over a socket, used by LoggingConfiguration
      enabled: false
      host: localhost
      port: 5000
      queue-size: 512
```

I am still an amateur in terms of docker and jhipster and so on. My guess is it is a small problem, maybe someone here can give me a pointer.